# C++ macro to generate const structs

Tags: c++, macros, variadic-functions

Is there a way to generate this kind of macro with some other macro?
E.g. a struct with 3 members or something...

```
#define CONST_STRUCT2(name, name1, type1, name2, type2) \
    struct name \
    { \
        name(const type1& p##name1, const type2& p##name2) \
          : name1(p##name1), name2(p##name2) {} \
         const type1 name1; const type2 name2; \
    };
```

Comment: Why the [varargs] tag?

Comment: Because I hope it is somehow solvable with variadic arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html).

```
#define CONST_STRUCT(name, members) \
  struct name \
  { \
    name(GENERATE_CTOR_PARAMS(members)) \
      : GENERATE_CTOR_INITIALISERS(members) {} \
    GENERATE_MEMBERS(members) \
  }


#define PARAM_TYPE(param) \
  BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, param)

#define PARAM_NAME(param) \
  BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, param)


#define GENERATE_CTOR_PARAMS(members) \
  BOOST_PP_ENUM(BOOST_PP_SEQ_SIZE(members), GENERATE_CTOR_PARAM, members)

#define GENERATE_CTOR_PARAM(z, idx, members) \
  const PARAM_TYPE(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(idx, members)) & PARAM_NAME(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(idx, members))


#define GENERATE_CTOR_INITIALISERS(members) \
  BOOST_PP_ENUM(BOOST_PP_SEQ_SIZE(members), GENERATE_CTOR_INITIALISER, members)

#define GENERATE_CTOR_INITIALISER(z, idx, members) \
  PARAM_NAME(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(idx, members)) (PARAM_NAME(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(idx, members)))


#define GENERATE_MEMBERS(members) \
  BOOST_PP_REPEAT(BOOST_PP_SEQ_SIZE(members), GENERATE_MEMBER, members)

#define GENERATE_MEMBER(z, idx, members) \
  const PARAM_TYPE(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(idx, members)) PARAM_NAME(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(idx, members));
```

Example of use:

```
CONST_STRUCT(Three, ((type1, name1))((type2, name2))((type3, name3)));
```

Necessary header files omitted for clarity. Also, in a real application, choose better scoped names (such as `CONST_STRUCT_GENERATE_...`).

Comment: This looks nice... although my coworkers probably kill me if I include boost. Do you think there is a way without boost?

Comment: @LarsSchneider I'm afraid not really. Technically, you could copy&paste the relevant parts of boost :-P But I'd say it would be more beneficial to convince your team not to fear boost. It's a pretty good and reliable library collection - why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @LarsSchneider Alternatively, resign on the custom member names and use `std::tuple`.